# interval between function calls with requestAnimationFrame varies

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I am trying to animate a Sequence of JPG images using requestAnimationFrame , however I noticed that sometime it takes a bit longer on some frames.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var start;
var i=0;
var animateLoop = function() {

    if(i>500) {
        return false;
    }
    i++;
    requestAnimFrame(animateLoop);
    var _start = start;
    start = +new Date();
    console.log("Iteration:"+i, "Milliseconds Diff: "+(start-_start));
   }

animateLoop();
```

To elaborate, please have a look at this fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/bhenqfbw/

If you run this while the console is open, you will see that the milliseconds difference between each call is not the same. and in my case where I change the image source in this function, the fluctuation is even higher.

is there a way I can make it constant or it just has to be this way ?

Comment: Well... you're not running in a real-time environment. This is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the point of `requestAnimationFrame` is for the browser to decide when to call that function again. It's optimized for that. Therefore that's the best option. Yet if you really want something aggressive that doesn't care whether the function finished being called `setInterval` is your friend (I mean enemy because it's pretty bad). Or:

```
function toCall(){
  //do stuff
  setTimeout(toCall); //Place this at the end of your function. And no second parameter needed. It'll be called whenever the stack is empty.
}
```

Comment: That won't really make it more accurate either. Recently did some testing - 30 image frames of a 17ms looped timeout (similar to common display refresh rate) amounted to 700+ total...

Comment: Well like I said `requestAnimationFrame` is his best choice. It also depends on how much work or how he's doing the work in his `animateLoop` function.

Comment: No argument there, just wanted to share recent findings. The log *is* rather interesting. Multiple 200+ durations but some also under 10ms. Without these seemingly being correlated. So it's odd to come across times much quicker than the display refresh rate.

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` is not time based. You should make your animation time based, not frame.

Basically if you want to change an element's position with a constant value and you don't have a fixed frame rate, you can use the time difference between frames to calculate the distance in each frame.

Here's the main idea: (check out console)
https://jsfiddle.net/bhenqfbw/1/